# Order django model by child and access distinct children in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-queryset

Let's say I have two classes:

```
class Event:
      name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Date:
      start = models.DateField()
      end = models.DateField()
      event = models.ForeignKey("event")
```

That is a calendar of events with multiple dates. Now I want to display all events ordered by their start date:

```
Event.objects.all().order_by('date__start')
```

That works fine and if I execute the sql I get exactly the result I need. However, if I want to display it in my template I run into a problem. Let me give you an example:

Date a starts at 24.12 and 31.12
Date b starts at 26.12

By executing the query above I get three Event objects in the order a, b, a. That's great. My problem is that both a-Events include both Date-children. Of course I want to display only the first date with the first a-object and the second date with the second a-object.

Comment: Your text is very confuse, put an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I changed my example to make it easier to understand, thanks.

Comment: What is the relationship between your models?

Comment: One event has many dates. I have recurring events I want to show in a calendar.

Comment: Have you tried `Date.objects.all().order_by('-start')`

Comment: I don't see why this should change anything. I think my use of the ORM here is just not allowed by its design :-/